# $\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_i$ cannot converge in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

> Let $X_n$ be iid random variables such that $E(X_i)=0$ and $E(X_i^2)=\sigma^2$. Prove that $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_i\right)_n$ cannot converge in probability.

I'm quite stumped with this problem. Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_i = \sqrt n \left(\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n X_i\right)$, $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_i\right)_n$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$, so the question essentially asks to prove that convergence cannot be improved to convergence in probability.

Supposing for the sake of contradiction that $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_i\right)_n$ converges to some $Y$ in probability, there exists a subsequence that converges to $Y$ almost surely. I haven't been able to derive anything useful from this...

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: If $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and $Y$ is independent from the $X_n$, what is the limiting distribution of $Y - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not sure what to answer. Can you flesh out the argument a bit more ?

Comment: Suppose we have $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ for all $i$. Then $Z_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Hence $Y - Z_n \sim \text{ what}$? But Sangchul Lee's answer avoids the assumption that $Y$ is independent from the $X_i$ and hence works with only the given assumptions, while my idea only shows why one should expect the result (under the assumption $\sigma^2 > 0$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a one possible way: Write

$$Z_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k$$

and assume that $(Z_n)$ converges in probability to some r.v. $Y$. By the classical CLT we know that $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.  Then $\sqrt{2}Z_{2n} - Z_n$ converges to $(\sqrt{2}-1)Y$ in probability. On the other hand, we know that

$$\sqrt{2}Z_{2n} - Z_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{n+k}$$

has the same distribution as $Z_n$, hence this must converge in distribution to $Y$. This forces that

$$ (\sqrt{2}-1)^2\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}((\sqrt{2}-1)Y) = \operatorname{Var}(Y) = \sigma^2, $$

from which we obtain $\sigma = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with the derivation, yet it seems very much out of the blue. Would me mind providing the rationale behind the path you've taken ? I wouldn't have thought about considering $\sqrt{2}Z_{2n} - Z_n$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon, A sequence needs to be eventually stabilized in some sense in order to converge in probability. In other words, most of the information for the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} Z_n$ can be extracted even by looking at a single term $Z_n$ for large $n$. This is exactly the contrary for CLT. In this case, any information over any fixed span of time (discrete time, I mean) is eventually smudged out. So if $1 \ll n \ll m$, $Z_m$ is almost independent of $Z_n$ even if they have almost identical distribution. And there is no doubt such sequence cannot converge in probability.

Comment: My argument is designed to exploit this behavior. Anyway, probably a more transparent way is to introduce $Z'_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{n+k}$ and write $$ Z_{2n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(Z_n + Z_n'). $$ If $Z_n \to Y$ in probability, then $Z'_n \to Y'$ in probability such that $Y$ and $Y'$ are i.i.d. But this tells that $$Y = \frac{Y+Y'}{\sqrt{2}}, $$ which is absurd since $Y$ contains something that is independent of $Y$!